# Why do I keep facing the same error in NextJs everytime I rerun my application after a while

Tags: next.js

Every time I come back to my next js app and I try to run with the npm run dev command, I face this error:

[Error: UNKNOWN: unknown error, readlink 'C:\Users\siddh\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-template.next\app-build-manifest.json'] {
type: 'Error',
errno: -4094,
code: 'UNKNOWN',
syscall: 'readlink',
path: 'C:\Users\user\OneDrive\Desktop\portfolio-template\.next\app-build-manifest.json'
}

Then I try to implement a solution I saw on stack overflow which told me to delete the .next directory and then to try to run the app. But after I do that I get this error:

- wait compiling /page (client and server)...
- error src\app\page.tsx
  page.tsx doesn't have a root layout. To fix this error, make sure every page has a root layout.
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- error src\app\page.tsx
  page.tsx doesn't have a root layout. To fix this error, make sure every page has a root layout.

Can someone tell what is the reason for this and how to fix it??

Then I try to implement a solution I saw on stack overflow which told me to delete the .next directory and then to try to run the app. But after I do that I get this error:

- wait compiling /page (client and server)...
- error src\app\page.tsx
  page.tsx doesn't have a root layout. To fix this error, make sure every page has a root layout.
- wait compiling /_error (client and server)...
- error src\app\page.tsx
  page.tsx doesn't have a root layout. To fix this error, make sure every page has a root layout.

Can someone tell what is the reason for this and how to fix it??